# Is there a better alternative for nested for-loops?

Tags: python, for-loop

Good day,

I would like to ask if there are better alternatives (or just in writing the code) for nested `for`-loops?
For example, right now I'm writing it like this:

```
list_a = [1, 1, 2 ,3]
list_b = [[1, 2], [3, 10]]

for a in list_a:
    for b in list_b:
        if a >= b[0] and a <= b[1]:
            # Do something here
            break
```

Comment: Do you want to break only from inner loop or from both loops?

Comment: this depends entirely on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Do you need mandatory `break`?

Comment: @devguy Only from inner loop!

Answer (score 1):

It really depends what you're trying to do. If you know that both lists have the same length, then you can use one loop. However, you would first want to `flatten` your nested list for `list_b` (which is almost like running two for loops but is more concise and is faster).

If you're asking about nested loops in order to sort a given array, then there are many resources you could find in google or youtube that are very helpful (mergeSort, quickSort).

At any rate, here is an example code:

```
list_a = [1, 1, 2 ,3]
list_b = [[1, 2], [3, 10]]
flattened_b = [item for sublist in list_b for item in sublist]
for idx in range(len(list_a)):
    print(list_a, flattened_b)
```

Interesting blog about flattening lists: http://rightfootin.blogspot.com/2006/09/more-on-python-flatten.html

Comment: " (which is almost like running two for loops but is more concise and is faster)" not really faster, no. In fact, this is almost certainly slower.